# Convert PHP Image Object to Byte Array for AMFPHP

Tags: php, flash, arrays, amfphp

I have a PHP image object created using imagecreatetruecolor(). I'd like to send this via AMFPHP to Flash. I understand the best format is using a ByteArray. How can I achieve this without writing the image to the disk?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer the raw resource, but the usual course of action is to use an `ob_start()` before the `imagepng/imagejpeg/imagegif` functions, and get it in a variable with `ob_get_clean()`. How it works with AMFPHP & ByteArrays is another matter, I have no experience with those.

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(30,40);
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$bytes = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: can you give me some example code for this. the amfphp bit i'm fine with.

Comment: Flash doesn't recognise the result as a valid ByteArray - any other ideas?

Comment: I have no clue what that expects as input. Any quick docs on that? (and it isn't a ByteArray yet, you do something like `$barr = new ByteArray($bytes);` I hope?).

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
imagepng($resource);
```

This will send the image from the memory to the browser